# A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL serer

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to connect to database in my server which is hosted on eris.ignitionserver.net:2083/. it is showing me error that network related error occured. i am posting my code here .. so Please provide me some help

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
     conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=eris.ignitionserver.net:2083; Initial  Catalog=TISDB; User id=abc; Password=12345;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
     conn.Open();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is right? Are you sure this is not a firewall problem or something?

Comment: Actually what i want to do is that i have server on cloud and i want to attach my database on my cloud server which is eris.ignitionserver and make SQL server connection to it.

Comment: Your should add  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" in your connection string

Comment: Several things: you should typically not have a `:2083` port number in your connection string - do you really need that specific port? SQL Server typically listens on port 1433.... also: you should *either* specify `Integrated Security=SSPI;` to use the current Windows credentials, *or* you should supply `User Id` and `Password` - but don't have *both* in there at the same time!

Comment: I tried as per you guided but still having same error